# Public key authorization on sftp chroot directory

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, chroot

I want to add public key authorization to my sftp chroot directory but I allways get:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Chroot works because authorization with password is possible.
I have other account on this host without chroot and it works with this key.
I tried many times, but still it doesn't work.

On server in auth.log there is only:
Connection closed by xxx [preauth]

This is my directory:

```
ls -laR /sftp/
/sftp/:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  3 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 May  3 14:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  3 16:45 backup

/sftp/backup:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 backup sftpusers 4096 May  3 16:55 incoming

/sftp/backup/incoming:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 backup sftpusers 4096 May  3 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:45 ..
drwx------ 2 backup sftpusers 4096 May  3 21:06 .ssh

/sftp/backup/incoming/.ssh:
total 12
drwx------ 2 backup sftpusers 4096 May  3 21:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 backup sftpusers 4096 May  3 16:55 ..
-rw------- 1 backup sftpusers  391 May  3 21:06 authorized_keys
```

My user:

```
backup:x:1002:1003::/incoming:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

My ssh config:

```
Match Group sftpusers
  ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
  AuthorizedKeysFile  /sftp/backup/incoming/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

Please help.

Answer (score 24):

I attempted this solution (putting AuthorizedKeysFile into the Match block) and `sshd -T` complains:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 153: Directive 'AuthorizedKeysFile' is not allowed within a Match block
```

(RHEL 6.6, openssh 5.3p1-104)

SOLUTION: The authorized_keys file (and the user's .ssh directory) must exist in the home directory location defined by /etc/passwd, **outside** of the chroot directory.

For example (using the OP usernames/uids):
/etc/passwd:

```
backup:x:1002:1003::/home/backup:/sbin/nologin
```

Create directory `/home/backup`, owned by root
Create directory `/home/backup/.ssh`, change ownership to backup, `chmod 700 /home/backup/.ssh`
Copy the authorized_keys file to `/home/backup/.ssh`, `chmod 400 authorized_keys`

```
ls -laR /home

/home:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Jul  9 12:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Sep 22 2014  ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Jul  9 12:25 backup

/home/backup:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Jul  9 12:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Jul  9 12:25 ..
drwx------ 3 backup   sftpusers 4096 Jul  9 12:28 .ssh

/home/backup/.ssh:
total 12
drwx------ 3 backup   sftpusers 4096 Jul  9 12:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 Jul  9 12:25 ..
-r-------- 3 backup   sftpusers 391  Jul  9 12:29 authorized_keys
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config becomes:

```
Match Group sftpusers
  ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

The chroot directory structure is then:

```
ls -laR /sftp/
/sftp/:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  3 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 May  3 14:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  3 16:45 backup

/sftp/backup:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 backup   sftpusers 4096 May  3 16:55 incoming
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:55 home

/sftp/backup/incoming:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 backup sftpusers 4096 May  3 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:45 ..

/sftp/backup/home:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:45 ..
drwx------ 2 backup   sftpusers 4096 May  3 21:06 backup

/sftp/backup/home/backup:
total 12
drwx------ 3 backup   sftpusers 4096 May  3 21:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root      4096 May  3 16:55 ..
```

Note: `/sftp/backup/home/backup` is empty, it's only there to provide a path that will look like the non-chroot `/home/backup` -- the `.ssh` directory is `/home/backup/.ssh` **not** `/sftp/backup/home/backup/.ssh`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that SELinux can bite you on Redhat distros. I found I needed to run `restorecon -R /home/backup/.ssh` in order to fix an 'Permission denied' error I was seeing in the sshd debug output.

Answer (score 14):

Problem resolved.

I have changed it:
AuthorizedKeysFile  /sftp/backup/incoming/.ssh/authorized_keys
to:
AuthorizedKeysFile /sftp/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 2):

[Stephen Buchanan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31477162/4289268) (which works around RHEL6's inability to set AuthorizedKeys in a Match block) splits keys into `/home` and contents into `/sftp`, but it is possible to keep everything together under `/home` instead.

You do this by creating the user's chroot under their home directory. For example, in `sshd_config`, set the chroot to `/home/<user>/sftp`:

```
Match Group sftphome
  ChrootDirectory /home/%u/sftp
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

As before, ensure `/home/<user>` is owned by root and place .ssh keys in `/home/<user>/.ssh` such that the user has read permissions. Now create `/home/<user>/sftp/home/<user>`, with all directories owned by root except for the last `<user>`, which should be owned by the user. Finally, ensure the user's home directory is `/home/<user>` in /etc/passwd.

Now when the user logs in, the ssh key is looked up in `/home/<user>/.ssh` as per `/etc/passwd`, a chroot is done into `/home/<user>/sftp`, and then a `cd` is done into `/home/<user>` *inside* the chroot. In other words, the user's remote working directory will appear as `/home/<user>`.

You can optionally bind mount directories under `/home/<user>/sftp/home/<user>`, or anywhere under `/home/<user>/sftp` (which is `/` from the user's point of view).

It's possible to omit the `sftp/` directory, create `/home/<user>/home/<user>` and chroot into `/home/<user>`, but this can be confusing as the `.ssh` directory and any other files will show up for the user in their `/`. The `sftp/` directory keeps things clean.

Note: In practice, if a user's home directory is missing, `sftp` will normally just `cd` into `/`. You *could* abuse this property by not creating `/home/<user>` inside the chroot, so the user starts in `/` instead of `/home/<user>`. This is a bit fragile, but could come in handy.

Comment: This is a perfect tip, @jursetto, chrooting to ~/sftp instead of to ~ directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add AuthorizedKeysFile /sftp/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. It is better if you added it in the match block.